# Connect to Azure SQL database via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I use pyodbc to connect to my local SQL database which works without issue.

```
SQLSERVERLOCAL='Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;integrated security = true;DATABASE=eodba;'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(SQLSERVERLOCAL)   #works
```

I tries to connect to the Azure SQL database with:

```
SQLSERVERAZURE='Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=tcp:mydatbase.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;Uid=myuser@myerver;Pwd=mypass;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(SQLSERVERAZURE)   #works not
```

which gives me the error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Any luck finding an answer to this? I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL database using SQL Alchemy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides the suggestions that provided by meet-bhagdev who recommended to use the pymssql driver that mentioned in [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-windows/), to resolve the error:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

that was encountered, please update your connection string as below.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=yoursqlAzureServer.database.windows.net,1433', user='yourName@yoursqlAzureServer', password='Password', database='DBName')
```

Answer (score 1):

Download ODBC driver from Microsoft website and try installing it. I guess then the problem should disappear.
Here is the link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420