# What is the name of the driver to connect to Azure SQL Database from pyodbc in Azure ML?

Tags: python, pyodbc, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service, cortana-intelligence

I'm trying to create a '**Reader**' alternative to read data from Azure SQL Database using the 'Execute python script' module in **Azure ML**.
While doing so, I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL using pyodbc library.

Here's my code:

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    import pyodbc   
    import pandas as pd

    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=server.database.windows.net; DATABASE=db_name; UID=user; PWD=Password')
    SQLCommand = ('''select * from table1 ''')
    data_frame = pd.read_sql(SQLCommand, conn)
    return data_frame,
```

also tried to use a different driver name: `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Does anybody know which driver should I use?

Just to make sure, I tried  `{SQL Server}`, `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}` and `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` and got the same error

I also tried a different format:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=server.database.windows.net; DATABASE=db_name; user=user@server; password=Password')
```

and

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; SERVER=server.database.windows.net; DATABASE=db_name; user=user@server; password=Password')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connect to Azure SQL database via pyodbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802199/connect-to-azure-sql-database-via-pyodbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from Azure support:

> Currently it is not possible to access SQL Azure dbs from within  an
> “execute python script” module. As you suspected this is due to
> missing odbc drivers in the execution environment.   Suggested
> workarounds are to  a) use reader module   or   b) export to blobs
> and use the Azure Python SDK for accessing those blobs
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2015/10/02/using-azure-sdk-for-python.aspx

So currently it it **impossible** to connect to SQL server from “execute python script” module in Azure-ML. If you like to change it, please vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/257792-machine-learning/suggestions/12589266-enable-odbc-connection-from-excute-python-script)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31412997/1431750), the connection string should be:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=yoursqlAzureServer.database.windows.net,1433', user='yourName@yoursqlAzureServer', password='Password', database='DBName')
```

Note the difference in the format: different params for user, password and database vs. all in one in the first string.

Also related, see this Azure page: [Connect to SQL Database by using Python on Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-windows/). It states using `pymssql`, with no mention of `pyodbc`.

Comment: @aberoid, I tried that as well, but this module is not available in Azure ML python scripts. when I tried it, it. I got "ImportError: No module named pymssql"

Comment: it's impossible to do in Azure-ML "Execute python script" module

Comment: did this using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/machine-learning-data-science-sample-data-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

You will need the Microsoft ODBC Driver to use pyodbc. You can download it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434. Once you download that, try using the following connection string:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; SERVER=server.database.windows.net; DATABASE=db_name; user=user@server; password=Password')
```

If this string does no work, try this one:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server.database.windows.net,1433', user='user@server', password='Password', database='db_name')
```

Comment: it's impossible to do in Azure-ML "Execute python script" module

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Database Driver name for Pyodbc should be `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` since some reasons below.

1. The connection string for SQL Database shown on Azure portal, please see the Fig 1 & Fig 2 below.

Fig 1. On Azure old portal
[image]

Fig 2. On Azure new portal (the version 11.0 later then v10.0)
[image]

2. According to [the Pyodbc code comments](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/tests3/sqlservertests.py#L14), please see the Fig 3 below.

Fig 3. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate source of truth :-) for connection strings is:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/

Use it as guide to construct yours.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: Server=tcp:[your server here].database.windows.net;Database=db_name;User ID=user@[your server here];Password=Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;

This should be your connection string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just tried it and got the same error. it might be something else, other than the connection string